# Do you use Will or would?

Tags: grammar

If someone does what you predicted do you say "I knew he would do that " or "I knew he'll do that" ?

Comment: Would is correct

Comment: Please provide more detail about the situation. It seems that "would" is correct here, but giving an answer without context is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

"**Would**" is correct.  You can say "I knew he would do that" or "I knew he'd do that".

"**Would**" is used as the past of "will". This form is known as "*the future in the past*".

The British Council website explains this [as follows](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/talking-about-past):

> When we talk about the future from a time in the past we use:
>
> **would** as the past tense of **will**
>
> *He thought he would buy one the next day.*
>
> *Everyone was excited. The party would be fun.*
>
> **was/were going to**
>
> *John was going to drive and Mary was going to follow on her bicycle.*
>
> *It was Friday. We were going to set off the next day.*
>
> the **past continuous**:
>
> *It was September. Mary was starting school the next week.*
>
> *We were very busy. The shop was opening in two weeks' time.*